# Monitor wordpress installations remotely

Tags: wordpress, plugins, monitoring

I would like to monitor all our wordpress installations on a single page to show the current version of the installation...

I don't know where to start... does we need to install a small plugin in the wordpress to push the version number to our monitor page?

I would like that our monitor page detect automaticaly when we add our monitor plugin to the wordpress intallation...

Thanks all...

Answer (score 0):

Write a plugin that connects to the database for each of your Wordpress installations and reads the attributes you need and displays it.